# Dockerfile for golang and python

Tags: python, django, docker, go

There is a django project already running. Now Inside the code,
I need to execute the following command in the subprocess module:

```
cmd = f's5cmd cp {obj1} {obj2}'
```

Now locally this code is running fine. But after deploying the code it is unable to find s5cmd. According to s5cmd documentation it is written in golang and on my system it is installed that's why it is working fine. So i updated the dockerfile but still its not working.

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . /apps/project/
WORKDIR /apps/project/project/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD gunicorn project.wsgi:application --timeout 3000 --access-logfile '-' -w 3 -k gevent --bind=0.0.0.0:8000
```

This dockerfile is working.
Now the updated dockerfile looks like this but its not working i.e the s5cmd command is not working with docker.

```
FROM python:3.6.7-alpine3.6

# author of file
LABEL maintainer="Baktawar"



# Install native libraries, required for numpy
RUN apk --no-cache add musl-dev linux-headers g++
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps bash gcc musl-dev openssl go
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates wget && update-ca-certificates
RUN wget -O go.tgz https://golang.org/dl/go1.15.2.src.tar.gz
RUN tar -C /usr/local -xzf go.tgz
RUN cd /usr/local/go/src/
RUN ./make.bash
RUN export PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH"
RUN export GOPATH=/opt/go/
RUN export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
RUN apk del .build-deps
RUN go version
RUN apk update && apk add git && go get github.com/peak/s5cmd && s5cmd
# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt && pip install psycopg2-binary
COPY . /apps/project/
WORKDIR /apps/project/project/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD gunicorn project.wsgi:application --timeout 3000 --access-logfile '-' -w 3 -k gevent --bind=0.0.0.0:8000
```

Requirements.txt file

```
boto3==1.12.39
botocore==1.15.39
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.2
djangorestframework==3.11.0
docutils==0.15.2
gevent==20.5.1
greenlet==0.4.16
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
jmespath==0.10.0
json-logging==1.2.0
numpy==1.19.0
pandas==1.0.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.16
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.9
zope.event==4.4
zope.interface==5.1.0
pytest==6.0.1
```

Comment: Is that an AWS S3 CLI tool?  Use [Boto](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) instead.  (And _never_ construct a command using string interpolation this way, it is a significant security issue...what happens if `obj1` contains a `;` in it?)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes it is an aws cli tool written in boto3 for high performance. I have used boto but each thread takes 10 mb and it sucks whole memory when used in production thatswhy I have to use this. obj1 and obj2 are just example in actual they are name of the files to copy from s3 bucket to local directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the Dockerfile:

1. `RUN cd /usr/local/go/src/` won't work, it should be replaced with `WORKDIR /usr/local/go/src` or placed inline with the next command
2. `RUN export PATH ...` (and the like) wont' work either, should be replaced with `ENV PATH ...`

The following Dockerfile should work (just the go/s5cmd part)

```
RUN apk --no-cache add musl-dev linux-headers g++
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps bash gcc musl-dev openssl go
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates wget && update-ca-certificates
RUN wget -O go.tgz https://golang.org/dl/go1.15.2.src.tar.gz
RUN tar -C /usr/local -xzf go.tgz
RUN cd /usr/local/go/src/ && ./make.bash
ENV PATH "/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH"
ENV GOPATH "/opt/go/"
ENV PATH "$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
RUN apk del .build-deps
RUN go version
RUN apk update && apk add git && go get github.com/peak/s5cmd && s5cmd
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply, but for the above dockerfile s5cmd command is also running. The problem comes when python requirements.txt start installing then for several packages it breaks i.e gevent==20.5.1, psycopg2-binary and when I change it to FROM python:3.6 in above then s5cmd is not installing and libraries are perfectly installed.

Comment: For the python:3.6 base image it fails because of missing `apk`. I'm not sure about python dependencies, you haven't provided requirements.txt, although in the first file there is no `pip install psycopg2-binary` while it's present in the second one.

Comment: I updated the question requirements.txt file
@Mafor In the above dockerfile psycopg2-binary is not there because it is not conflicting in first but in second it is conflicting so I tried like this.

Comment: What is your question/ problem now? Please clarify it.